# $1/p^2+1/q^2+1/r^2\geq 27$ given that $p,q,r > 0$ and $p+q+r=1$

Tags: inequality

I wish to prove that $1/p^2+1/q^2+1/r^2\geq 27$ given that $p,q,r > 0$ and $p+q+r=1$

I have successfully shown that $$\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}\geq9$$ but I am not too sure how to progress.

I have tried expanding: 
$$(p+q+r)^2\times \left (\frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{q^2}+\frac{1}{r^2} \right) $$

and have gotten close, but there has always been terms that I cannot get rid of.

Some assistance would be extremely helpful here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1/p^2+1/q^2+1/r^2\ge3/(pqr)^{2/3}$

Now $1=p+q+r\ge3(pqr)^{1/3}\iff1/(pqr)^{1/3}\ge3$

Comment: The power mean inequality strikes again!

Answer (score 0):

Apply CS inequality then

{(1/p^2)+(1/q)^2+(1/r)^2}{1+1+1}>={1/p+1/q+1/r}^2 and put  your result you will get the solution

Answer (score 0):

By Holder
$$\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}=(x+y+z)^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)\geq(1+1+1)^3=27.$$

Answer (score 0):

One more hint, $1/t^2$ is convex, so Jensen inequality applies...